# Json to Object Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a Json object like so:

```
{
  "key" : "false",
  "key2" : "1.00",
  "key3" : "value"
}
```

How can I convert this in Typescript to get

```
{
  "key" : false,
  "key2" : 1.00,
  "key3" : "value"
}
```

I have tried using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))`, `JSON.parse(json)` and `Object.assign(object, json)` but none of those solutions seem to work.

Comment: objects can have only unique keys. what you requested (with 3 exactly the same keys) - is not possible.

Comment: Re: duplicate keys, perhaps what you want is Record<string, boolean | number | string>.  The Record utility type doesn’t specify particular keys, but it says that an object has keys of one type (string) with values of another type (boolean, number, or string).

Comment: @falinsky There aren't supposed to be any duplicate keys. It was just a typing mistake, but fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `JSON.parse` will not automatically convert strings that happen to represent valid values of primitives such as booleans and floats. It simply keeps them as strings. For a simple case, such as the one you have given, it's easy enough to manually convert the strings:

```
let src = { "key": "false", "key2": "1.00", "key3": "value" };
let dst = {
    key: src.key !== "true",
    key2: parseFloat(src.key2),
    key3: src.key3
};
```

Comment: This would not be an ideal solution if I had more than 10+ or even 100+ items to go through